# Jenkins Pipeline - how to compare to file paths if I can't use Java Path class?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

In Java, I would use Paths to compare two files paths, to make sure path1 could be a child of path2.

```
Path path1 = Paths.get("/path/to/jenkins/workspace1").normalize();
Path path2 = Paths.get("/path/to/jenkins/workspace1/some/dir").normalize();

path2.startsWith(path1);
```

I can't seem to use the Path class in pipeline. How would you compare this in groovy?

There doesn't seem to be a good way other than splitting the two strings into lists and making sure element i from path1 matches element i from path2.

What I'm trying to do is add a check to my build job that validates that path2 (a named, mounted build dependency) is indeed inside path1 (my workspace root).

For example, if path1 = "/some/path/to/jenkins/workspace1" and path2 = "/some/path/to/jenkins/workspace2/some/dir", I should fail the build as a fail safe.

Comment: Why don't you use Strings? you have myStringVar.startsWith(theOtherPrefixString) method.

Comment: @Rcordoval I think that algorithm would fail for certain situations e.g. relative pathing.

Comment: @Rcordoval, strings aren't paths... e.g. first="/some/path/dir" and second="/some/path/dir2"... second.startsWith(first) == true.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to import Paths by using a global pipeline library and calling the comparison method from that. Somewhat ugly, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://www.oipapio.com/question-4389341). you can use the `URI` class to generate normalized paths, and then use string comparison:

```
def path1 = new URI("/path/to/jenkins/workspace1").normalize().toString()
def path2 = new URI("/path/to/jenkins/workspace1/some/dir").normalize().toString()
path2.startsWith(path1)
```